# Apply background color in algorithm environment

Tags: algorithm2e

I have not found a simple solution to have a background color in the algorithm environment. Can you help me put a background.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\begin{document}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
This is line one\\
This is line two numbered\\
This should be numbered\\
This should also be numbered
\caption{Unnumbered lines}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do to center an algorithm with a gray background :

```
\begin{center}
\colorbox[gray]{0.95}{
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
This is line one\\
This is line two numbered\\
This should be numbered\\
This should also be numbered
\caption{Unnumbered lines}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I was trying to modify your code to work with other colors like blue or `\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}`.  When I tried to change the color, I could not compile the code. I changed the line `\colorbox[gray]{0.95}{`  to  `\colorbox[blue]{0.95}{` and I got the error `! Package xcolor Error:  Underined color model blue`.  How do you go about changing the background color?  Thanks!

Comment: For posterity: the solution I used for the above comment by @Joe was to write \colorbox[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 1} for a box that is lightly shaded blue.  Parameters {0, 0, 0} give black and {1, 1, 1} give white, and you can interpolate between these.

Answer (score 3):

**This is PART II of my answer to the above comment of @Joe:** (Due to low reputation points, I can't post more than 8 links in the first part of my answer.)

We now illustrate the obtained `RGB` color specification `{239,240,241}` with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
     \colorbox[RGB]{239,240,241}{
         \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
              \begin{algorithm}[H]
                    \SetAlgoLined
                    \KwData{this text}
                    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
                    initialization\;
                    \While{not at end of this document}{
                         read current\;
                         \eIf{understand}{
                             go to next section\;
                             current section becomes this one\;
                         }{
                             go back to the beginning of current section\;
                         }
                     }
                     \caption{How to write algorithms}
               \end{algorithm}
          \end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and it outputs the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**This is PART I of my answer to the above comment of @Joe:** (since I don't have enough reputation points)

**Answer:** Your problem is actually with regards to color models. Kindly look at the [**Color Models** subsection in Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Color_Models). I have slightly modified the code of @pzorba75 using the `rgb` model with color specification `{0.74,0.83,1}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
   \colorbox[rgb]{0.74,0.83,1}{
        \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
            \SetAlgoLined
            \SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
            \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \DontPrintSemicolon
                  This is line one\\
                  This is line two numbered\\
                  This should be numbered\\
                  This should also be numbered
                  \caption{Unnumbered lines}
                  \end{algorithm}
      \end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this: [image]

**Remark:**

Well, of course, you can choose different color specifications. For some list to choose from, [click this link](http://latexcolor.com/).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always post *compilable* code snippets to answer the question (especially if you changed preamble and document).

Comment: @TeXnician, I have edited by your requirements. Thankful for the comment.

Comment: Suggestion to remove **UPDATE** part. This is off-topic for tex.se