# Apply background color in algorithm environment part 2

Tags: algorithm2e

This question is building of the solution found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305967/apply-background-color-in-algorithm-environment).  I wanted to change the background color to blue or a user defined color `\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}`.  However when I tried to implement the line

```
\colorbox[mybluei]{0.95}{
```

I get the error `! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model 'mybluei'`

Please help me change the background color.  Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{center}
\colorbox[gray]{0.95}{
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
This is line one\\
This is line two numbered\\
This should be numbered\\
This should also be numbered
\caption{Unnumbered lines}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\colorbox{mybluei}{\color{red}
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
This is line one\\
This is line two numbered\\
This should be numbered\\
This should also be numbered\\ 
\vspace{1cm}
\caption{Unnumbered lines}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: mini]