# Apply background color in algorithm2e (but not on the caption)

Tags: color, algorithm2e

This article [Apply background color in algorithm environment part 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306021/apply-background-color-in-algorithm-environment-part-2) show how to change the background color of an algorithm, using the package `algorithm2e`.

I would like to do the same, but only on the code itself so that the caption keeps the page background color.

MNE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\SetAlCapSkip{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \colorbox{gray!20}{
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
        This is line one\\
        This is line two
        \caption{Some Title.}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I obtain:

[image: Result]

"Algorithm 1: Some Title" should be with a white background color.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible, but have to fake the option "`ruled`" which is by default in the algorithm package and the tag was given below:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{framed,xcolor}

\SetAlCapSkip{1em}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.15}
\makeatletter
\def\@algocf@pre@ruled{\begin{shaded}}%
\def\@algocf@post@ruled{\end{shaded}\relax}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

      \begin{algorithm}[H]
        This is line one\\
        This is line two
        \caption{Some Title.}
    \end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the command `{\algocf@algoframe}` after `\begin{shaded}` seems unnecerssary and produce an unwanted character at the beginning of the algorithm.

Comment: Please check the modified answer...

Answer (score 0):

In the next release 5.3 that is still in beta, I have added two options: *shaded* and *title shaded* that allow to shade background of algorithm and background of title.
You can get in on [my home page](http://www.lirmm.fr/users/utilisateurs-lirmm/christophe-fiorio/algorithm2e-style-package)

Be aware that this is still in beta and even if these options have been tested, not all interactions possible between options and packages have yet been tested.

Comment: Hi Fiorio, there seems to be no content under algorithm2e 5.3's page: http://www.lirmm.fr/users/utilisateurs-lirmm/christophe-fiorio/algorithm2e-style-package/algorithm2e.sty-r5.3