# Background color algorithm - particular line

Tags: algorithms

I want to apply background color to a particular line within an algorithm. Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305967/apply-background-color-in-algorithm-environment), I have the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
            \null   
            \begin{algorithm}[H]
                \caption{Puda}\label{puda}
                \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                    \State \colorbox[RGB]{239,240,241}{Hu}
                    \State Hu
                    \Return 
                \end{algorithmic}
            \end{algorithm}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{document}
```

and the output:
[image]

I want that the rest of the line is filled with the same background color (marked in yellow). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some solution with manual tweaks. The macro `\colorline` wraps its content inside a `\colorbox` and corrects some alignment issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}
\newcommand{\colorline}[1]{
\hspace{-0.03\linewidth}\colorbox{gray!30}{\makebox[0.99\linewidth][l]{Hu}}
 }

    \begin{document}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
            \null   
            \begin{algorithm}[H]
                \caption{Puda}\label{puda}
                \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                    \State \colorline{Hu}
                    \State Hu
                    \Return 
                \end{algorithmic}
            \end{algorithm}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{document}
```